# Legal obligations freelancer - Taxes and NI

Tags: legal, taxes, invoices, uk

I am a EU citizen living in the UK. I need to invoice an US client via pay pal, during 6 months. Do I need to include VAT in my invoice? What are my legal obligations in the UK towards taxes and NI as a freelancer? Thank you

Comment: Just to confirm: NI = Northern Ireland?

Comment: National Insurance is what Christina means.

Comment: NI conts are a personal liability and unrelated to where your clients are located. If you also have an Ltd company you will need to be paying employer's contributions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should start here:

https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration/when-to-register

If your income as a freelancer does not exceed the threshold of £82,000 a year you don't need to worry about VAT at all. You usually only charge VAT within the EU and you must register first.

Comment: As of January 2015, if you sell to someone in the EU you need to register for VAT and charge VAT based on the client/customer's country. Look up "VATMOSS" for more info. (Still, it means nothing when selling outside of the EU)